# How to recover a forgotten Apple ID without access to a trusted device or a IOS device

Tags: apple-id, password

iPhone is considered to be the best in case of security. What should be done if the Apple ID is lost or forgotten and the iPhone is turned off, and there is no other way to start it?

This has happened with me twice and this time the problem is again the same. It's a big loss for me to buy a new iPhone every time. Please give me best guide so I can fix this problem.

Comment: dear sir i have really tried and do search for this problem. Sir this is not a duplicate  question as you can see that in other question  the connection is without IOS device but in my question i asked about the id that is forgotten without accessing to a trustful device so dear sir if you put my question as duplicate so who can see that and give my the best guide i want to get

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to recover an Apple ID even if you have forgotten your login email and password. Refer to the Apple Support article, [If you forgot your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201354).

> #### Use your Apple ID account page
>
> 1. Go to your [Apple ID account page](https://appleid.apple.com/) and click Forgot Apple ID or password.
> 2. When you're asked to enter your Apple ID, click If you forgot your Apple ID, you can look it up.
> 3. Enter your first name, last name, and email address. If you enter the wrong email address, you can try again with a different one.

Comment: dear sir i did it earlier but found no best solution but thanks